# How to compare current generating excel and previously generated excel to remove all the matching rows in excel interop?

Tags: c#, sql, office-interop, excel-interop

I have created a trigger statement in my database table and the data will be stored in a new physical table. Now I have created a console application to extract the data from physical table into excel sheet using excel interop.

Each time i run the application, I only want the not exported data to show in the new excel instead of showing everything. Its like I want to compare with previously generated excel and remove the data that is already in there in the currently generating excel.

For example:
**Stock.xls data:**
A
B
C

**Database Table data :**
A
B
C

When I run the application for the second time (I have added a new row in physical table in db, so the new xl sheet should remove a,b,c (and only must show d))

**Stock.xls data:**
D

**Database Table data :**
A
B
C
D

This is my code :

```cs
string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IntegrationConnection"].ConnectionString;
string sql2 = null;
string data2 = null;
int k = 0;
int l = 0;
string Filename2 = @"D:\Integration\Stock.xls";
if (!File.Exists(Filename2))
{
    File.Create(Filename2).Dispose();
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Filename2))
    {
        tw.WriteLine("Please run the program again");
        tw.Close();
    }
}

////*** Preparing excel Application
Excel.Application xlApp2;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook2;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2;
object misValue2 = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

///*** Opening Excel application
xlApp2 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(Filename2);
xlWorkSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)(xlWorkBook2.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet);

xlApp2.DisplayAlerts = false;
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
conn2.Open();

sql2 = "SELECT * from tblMPartHistory";

///*** Preparing to retrieve value from the database
DataTable dtable2 = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter dscmd2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2, conn2);
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
dscmd2.Fill(dtable2);

////*** Generating the column Names here
string[] colNames2 = new string[dtable2.Columns.Count];
int col2 = 0;

foreach (DataColumn dc in dtable2.Columns)
    colNames2[col2++] = dc.ColumnName;

char lastColumn2 = (char)(51 + dtable2.Columns.Count - 1);

xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", lastColumn2 + "1").Value2 = colNames2;
xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", lastColumn2 + "1").Font.Bold = true;

xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", lastColumn2 + "1").VerticalAlignment
                   = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

/////*** Inserting the Column and Values into Excel file
for (k = 0; k <= dtable2.Rows.Count - 1; k++)
{
    for (l = 0; l <= dtable2.Columns.Count - 1; l++)
    {
        data2 = dtable2.Rows[k].ItemArray[l].ToString();
        xlWorkSheet2.Cells[k + 2, l + 1] = data2;
        xlWorkBook2.Save();
    }
}

xlWorkBook2.Close(true, misValue2, misValue2);
xlApp2.Quit();

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet2);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook2);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp2);
```

Comment: You need to elaborate/rephrase/clearly explain what you mean by… _”Each time i run the application, I only want the not exported data to show in the new excel instead of showing everything. Its like I want to compare with previously generated excel and remove the data that is already in there in the currently generating excel.”_ … this is difficult to understand what you want. It sounds like you want to “compare” the data in an “existing” worksheet with some other data?

Comment: I have edited the question and post back, please look into it if you can understand now

Comment: We don't do "urgent" here on Stack Overflow. Please refrain from pleas of urgency, or any other language that would state or imply that your question is somehow of higher priority than any other unanswered question on the site.

Comment: Add a column to your table, change your export process to update that column first, then export....?

Comment: It is still not clear… _”I have added a new row in physical table in db, so the new xl sheet should remove a,b,c”_ ? … a “new” xl sheet won’t have “abc” to remove! Do you mean the “existing” worksheet should remove “ABC”? Also, it is not clear what “added a new row in physical table” has to do with the excel worksheet. Please take more time to clearly define what you are asking.

Comment: John G, But whenever i run the program, the new excel still show A, B, C. Thats what I want to get rid of here.

Comment: When you “open” an existing file, like the excel file with… `xlWorkBook2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(Filename2);` … THEN, it will obviously “contain” the existing data. Unless you “remove” the existing data or overwrite it, then it will remain when calling “Save” or “SaveAs.” Therefore, if you want an excel file without the existing data, then you need to create a “NEW” excel file (without opening the existing file)… then “save/overwrite” the existing one with the new one you created.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I understand your question:

You have a Database table and you want to generate a new excel sheet every time new rows have been 'commited' to your database, reflecting the recently added data only.

Of course you could go with your approach and just compare the data to all of your recent excel sheets, to remove duplicates.

A better approach would be though to add either a timestamp or a session-id to your dataset.
Then you can query your database for it and generate the new sheet from all the rows with the latest matching timestamp or highest matching session-id.

This way you will not only spare the extra work of the duplicate removal, but you'd also be able to restore all the sheets when they get lost somehow.

Comment: I have timestamp(GetDate()) in my table now. But how to implement timestamp in this code to only get recently added data? please help me how to do this?

Comment: The easiest method is to add a session-id for every write to the database.
So in your database-post you check for the session-id of the last entry, increment it by 1, and post all the new data with that session-id. 
Your sheet generator can then query all the rows with matching session-id of the last entry in your database and create the new sheet from them.
This is just an example though, you have to think through the specific implementation details yourself.

Comment: sql2 = "SELECT * from tblMPartHistory"; update this query accordingly to only get the entries that match the latest session-id.